# How do i style the rows in a GridView?

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview, ismouseover

I have a WPF project where i have a GridView nested inside a ListView and i want to change the style for the rows.

I want to change the color for when the cursor is above.

How do i do that?

Here is my XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="list_User_Events" Background="{StaticResource BorderDarkGreen}" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionMode="Single">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"></GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Interval" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Interval}"></GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Width="160" Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EventType}"></GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Command" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Command}"></GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Action">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="btn_list_user_Event_Delete" Click="btn_list_user_Event_Delete_Click">Delete</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Sounds like you set ItemContainerStyle to a Style with `TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"`

Comment: Wow that simple. That did it, thanks! Please provide answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Awesome! I revved up VS to make sure it would work but I was still defining a throwaway viewmodel class when you got it resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set the ItemContainerStyle on the ListView to a Style with a TargetType of ListViewItem:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="list_User_Events" 
    Background="{StaticResource BorderDarkGreen}" 
    Foreground="White" 
    BorderThickness="0" 
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
    SelectionMode="Single"
    >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <!-- Setters, Triggers, etc. -->
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.View>
        <!-- etc. etc. snip snip -->
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If you want to reuse the style for multiple similar listviews, you would define it in Window.Resources or UserControl.Resources with an `x:Key` attribute and use it as a static resource:

```
<ListView
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewGridViewItemStyle}"
```